# (django) my login and signup directly add / at the end even when i manually type in url where as contact and other seems to work fine

Tags: python, django

[contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9ee.png)
[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3V6P.png)
`view.py`

```
<pre><code>
def login(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
      if user is not None:
         auth.login(request,user)
         return redirect('/')
      else:
         messages.info(request,'Invalid Credendials')
         return redirect('login')
   return render(request,'login.html')

def contact(request):

   return render(request,'contact.html')
<code><pre>
```

`urls.py`

```
<pre><code>
   path('login',views.login,name='login'),
   path('contact',views.contact,name='contact'),
<code><pre>
```

`I was expecting to put login in without adding / at the end. changing urls.py seems to work but would be                 better if i can make it like this  without /`  [contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9ee.png)

`urls.py`

```
        path('login/',views.login,name='login')
```

Answer (score 0):

in setting.py put 
***APPEND_SLASH*** = False
Add manually as newer version off django have it in CommonMiddleware of middleware
You can read more here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/